# Will eBPF verify and jit the same bytecode?

Tags: runtime, jit, ebpf

I'm new to eBPF, I know that eBPF is a runtime and will verify the bytecode and jit it. So I wonder if eBPF will repeatedly verify and jit the same bytecode?

Comment: What do you mean by repeatedly? If someone loads the same program several times? While it is running?

Comment: yeah, both cases  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you reload the same program, then yes, the kernel will have to verify it and JIT-compile it again. But once it is loaded, it doesn't need to be verified or JIT-compiled again during its lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

When you load a program JIT-compiling happens just once - that's the advantage of JIT-compiling, you don't need to recompile everytime you run.

If you were to load several times the same bytecode with the JIT-compiler enabled, then yes, your program would be JIT-compiled mostly identically. The only difference I can think of would be map pointers that are inserted when the kernel inlines map access, and that may differ if the programs point to different maps.